# Export dataframe to csv date type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the dataframe (below) to csv file only with year from `Tarih` and value from `Veri`:

```
        Tarih  Veri
0  1960-01-01     0
1  1961-01-01     0
2  1962-01-01     0
3  1963-01-01     0
4  1964-01-01     0
5  1965-01-01     0
6  1966-01-01     0
7  1967-01-01     0
8  1968-01-01     0
9  1969-01-01     0
10 1970-01-01     0
```

I use this function:

```
df= pandas.read_excel(path)
df.to_csv(newPath, header=True, index=False, decimal=",", date_format="%Y")
```

But it exports like that in newPath.csv file(without `Veri` column):

```
Tarih,Veri
1960
1961
1962
1963
1964
1965
1966
1967
1968
1969
1970
```

If I use `date_format="%Y,%m"` or `date_format="%Y,%m,%d"` it gives right result. Even I use date_format like that: `date_format="%Y,"`(it gives 1960,,0 but gives `Veri`) or `date_format="%Y "`(leaving a space after Y; it gives 1960 ,0 but gives `Veri`).

How can I get this csv file by using this function:

```
Tarih,Veri
1960,0
1961,0
1962,0
1963,0
1964,0
1965,0
1966,0
1967,0
1968,0
1969,0
1970,0
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: So `df.to_csv(newPath, index=False, date_format='%Y')` just doesn't work?

Comment: It works for me. pandas 0.22

Comment: Can you provide `df.info()` for your dataframe? Probably it's about data types.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, a workaround that might work for you:

```
df = df.set_index('Tarih')

df.to_csv(newPath, header=True, index=True, decimal=",", date_format="%Y")
```

This will set the index to the 'Tarih' column and outputs it in the csv file.